# How can I grab and show the reader comments of my site

Tags: comments

How can I grab and show the reader comments of my news site in a different page?

Suppose, I have comments on a news site, into my posts. I want to show the comments (only the comments) into a different page of my site. How can I show all the news comments of my site?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you [researched the WordPress Codex for comment-related functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=comments+site%3Acodex.wordpress.org)?

Answer (score 1):

Sohag, you are seeking `get_comments()`.
See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

```
<?php $args= array(
    'author_email' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'karma' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'orderby' => '',
    'order' => 'DESC', //ASC or DESC
    'parent' => '',
    'post_id' => 0,
    'post_author' => '',
    'post_name' => '',
    'post_parent' => '',
    'post_status' => '',
    'post_type' => '',
    'status' => 'approve', //approve, hold, spam, trash
    'type' => '',
    'user_id' => '',
    'search' => '',
    'count' => false,
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'meta_query' => '',
);

$wpse_comments = get_comments( $args );

foreach( $wpse_comments as $s_comment ) :
    echo $s_comment->comment_author;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $s_comment->comment_content;
endforeach;

?>
```

Make a different [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and use the code into it. Hope you can figure out what the code is saying. No need to copy all the arguments from here, just take the arguments you need and rest the other in peace.

Try `<?php var_dump( $wpse_comments ); ?>` to see what are the properties you got with the query, and then use them accordingly.